# Latextools does not display cite keys if .tex file is in subfolder

Tags: latex, sublimetext2, bibtex

The wonderful **LatexTools** plugin for Sublime Text 2 autocompletes references when using `\cite`. Everything works perfectly when the `.bib` filed is in the same folder as the `.tex` file, and the .tex file includes the `\bibliography` command.

Unfortunately, for my larger projects, I keep my chapter `.tex` files in a subfolder. The `\bibliography` command only appears once in the master .tex file, and the `.bib` file lives with the master .tex file.

Is there a way to "point" LatexTools to my bibliography for all of the sub .tex files which do not include the `\bibliography` command, so that I can get autocomplete working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LatexTools searches for a root file that is specified in the subfile you are editing. When it finds such a file, it will look for bibliography related commands there and load the corresponding data. You provide the root file by placing the line

`%!TEX root = ../my_main_file.tex`

in the (first line of the) subfile.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you so much! For command line newbies, .. takes you up one folder level.